# Guidance needed on how to sort items when some are grouped together

Tags: mysql

I have a table that holds items:

```
id      name         groups 
1       a1          
2       a2           b1
3       a3
4       c1           
5       c2
6       c3           b1
```

I'd like to figure out an effective way to sort these items by `name` if `groups` does not exist (read: has no entry - null), or if `groups` exists, sort using the `groups`.

So if I were to sort the following table, the result would be:

```
a1
a3
a2
c3
c1
c2
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Define "does not exists"

Comment: If `groups` is null or blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "blank" means either `null` or `''`, use this:

```
select id, name, groups
from mytable
order by if(groups is null or groups = '', name, groups)
```

If "blank" means just `null`, then this simpler version will work:

```
select id, name, groups
from mytable
order by ifnull(groups, name)
```

Comment: You had a version earlier using `ifnull()` would that still work if all the entries defaulted to null? Could you also put that version back up as well?

Comment: No problem. I changed it to cater for your later comment. Both versions are there now.

Answer (score 1):

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN groups = '' OR groups IS NULL THEN name ELSE groups END
```